# Fetching checkbox and radio fields with PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf, pdfminer

My project involves reading text from a bunch of PDF form files for which I'm using [PyPDF2](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/) open source library. There is no issue in getting the text data as follows:

```
reader = PdfReader("data/test.pdf")
cnt = len(reader.pages)
print("reading pdf (%d pages)" % cnt)
page = reader.pages[cnt-1]
lines = page.extract_text().splitlines()
print("%d lines extracted..." % len(lines))
```

However, this text doesn't contain the checked statuses of the radio and checkboxes. I just get normal text (like `Yes No` or `Check-1  Check-2  Check-3` for example) instead of these values.

I also tried the `reader.get_fields()` and `reader.get_form_text_fields()` methods as described in [their documentation](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/forms.html) but they return empty values. I also tried reading it [through annotations](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/reading-pdf-annotations.html) but no `"/Annots"` found on the page. When I open the PDF in a `notepad++` to see its meta data, this is what I get:

```
%PDF-1.4
%²³´µ
%Generated by ExpertPdf v9.2.2
```

It appears to me that these checkboxes aren't usual form fields used in PDF but appear similar to HTML elements. Is there any way to extract these fields using python?

Finally, I've also tried `pdfminer.six`, the other popular pdf library for python with same results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the PDF you have contains XFA forms, which are not supported by the pdfminer.six library.

You may try [this](https://github.com/AF-VCD/pdf-xfa-tools) tool to extract the XFA forms.

If your PDF does not contain XFA forms, you can extract the form field and value data using the following snippet from [pdfminer.six docs](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/acro_forms.html)

```py
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1
from pdfminer.psparser import PSLiteral, PSKeyword
from pdfminer.utils import decode_text


data = {}


def decode_value(value):

    # decode PSLiteral, PSKeyword
    if isinstance(value, (PSLiteral, PSKeyword)):
        value = value.name

    # decode bytes
    if isinstance(value, bytes):
        value = decode_text(value)

    return value


with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
    parser = PDFParser(fp)

    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    res = resolve1(doc.catalog)

    if 'AcroForm' not in res:
        raise ValueError("No AcroForm Found")

    fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']  # may need further resolving

    for f in fields:
        field = resolve1(f)
        name, values = field.get('T'), field.get('V')

        # decode name
        name = decode_text(name)

        # resolve indirect obj
        values = resolve1(values)

        # decode value(s)
        if isinstance(values, list):
            values = [decode_value(v) for v in values]
        else:
            values = decode_value(values)

        data.update({name: values})

        print(name, values)
```

If the above code throws `No AcroForm found` error, that means your PDF most probably contains XFA forms.